# How to deploy a Flask app with Nginx and uWSGI?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, deployment, uwsgi

I need to deploy a flask app with Nginx and uWSGI and pass the test cases.

Here is my code.

**deploy.conf**

```
server {
    listen 8000;

    location /Hello { 
        include uwsgi_params; 
        uwsgi_pass localhost:8081; 
    }
}
```

**api.py**

```py
from flask import Flask, request, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "Thisisyoursecret"

@app.route('/Hello')
def hello():
    res=make_response("Welcome to your flask application")
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

**uwsgi.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:8081
module = wsgi:app
master = true
processes = 5
```

**wsgi.py**

```py
from api import app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**Here is the test case:**

```py
def test_hello_from_nginx_server(self):
    url = "http://localhost:8000/Hello"
    response = requests.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.text == 'Welcome to your flask application'
```

**Here is the error:**
*assert 502 == 200*

Why am I getting status code 502?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you enabled `CORS`?

Comment: Are you able to access the application on `http://localhost:8081/Hello`?

Comment: @DiegoBorba I tried to enable CORS like this, but I still get the same error:


server {
    listen 8000;
    
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

    location /Hello { 
        include uwsgi_params; 
        uwsgi_pass localhost:8081; 
    }
}

Comment: @Geilmaker There is a test case that accesses http://localhost:8081/Hello and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you have a try if the following `deploy.conf` works?

```
server {
    listen 8000;

    location /Hello { 
        proxy_pass localhost:8081; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, it worked with proxy_pass!

Comment: Nice to hear! Please consider to mark the answer as the "correct" answer :)